# Trouble understanding Passive-View in MVP Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mvp, passive-view

I'm trying to use the MVP (Passive View) pattern in a Winforms application. As far as I understand, in the Passive View implementation of MVP, the View doesn't know about the Presenter, so I need to communicate with it somehow. I'm using events for this. However, I'm having a problem: when the `TextChanged` event is fired in the View, the `FileName` field has already been changed by the time the `OnSetName()` method is called in the Presenter. This causes issues because I thought that the View in MVP would remain completely passive. For example, I want to have logic in the Presenter to avoid accepting certain names, but when I reach the `OnSetName()` method, it's already too late because the name has already been set.

```
public partial class Form1 : IPassiveView
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get => textEdit1.Text;
        set => textEdit1.Text = value;
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> NameChanged;

    private void textEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnNameChanged(FileName);
    }

    protected virtual void OnNameChanged(string e)
    {
        NameChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}

public interface IPassiveView
{
    string FileName { get; set; }

    event EventHandler<string> NameChanged;
}

public sealed class Presenter
{
    private readonly IPassiveView _view;
    public Presenter(IPassiveView view)
    {
        _view = view;
        _view.NameChanged += (sender, s) => OnSetName(s);
    }

    public void OnSetName(string name)
    {
        _view.FileName = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a recursive circle implementation. When the text value is changed of `TextEdit1` the event is fired. This event updates the `FileName` property. When this propery is set, is sets the `Text` of `TextEdit1`. This will fire the event again. See what is happening? What is the purpose of setting the 'TextEdit.Text'? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Stefan I know! And to my surprise it does not actually fire in a loop. My problem is not that though. My question is am I doing the Passive-View implementation of MVP correctly?